# Possible symmetry groups of a tetrahedron

Tags: permutations, finite-groups, symmetry, isometry

A symmetry of a figure $\mathcal{H}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an isometry which keeps $\mathcal{H}$ invariant. The set of all symmetries of $\mathcal{H}$ obviously form a group. We know that the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron is isomorphic to $S_4$, which consists of 24 elements.

My question is: ''What are possible symmetry groups of a tetrahedron (possibly nonregular)?''. I can show that a symmetry of a tetrahedron will send vertices to vertices, so its symmetry group is a subgroup of $S_4$. However it seems that not all subgroups of $S_4$ can be realised as the symmetry group of a tetrahedron. For instance, I tried to find tetrahedrons whose symmetry groups are of order 3, 4, 8 and 12 but I didn't succeed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd have another think about orders $4$ and $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry group of order $3$ cannot happen. Let tetrahedron have vvertices $1,2,3,4$. Subgroups of order $3$ of $S_4$ are generated by three-cycles $(a,b,c)$. WLOG we can assume it is $(1,2,3)$. Then the edge $[13]$ should go to $[21]$ under a symmetry which must fix $4$. Therefore edges $[14].[24],[34]$ have equal lengths and $[12],[23]$ have equal lengths. But then the permutation $(13)$ is a symmetry and the group of symmetries must have even order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed by what you said an element of a symmetry group of order 3 must be a 3-cycle which permutes 3 vertices, say $(1,2,3)$, and thus it fixes vertex 4. Then by the classification of isometries in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we see that any 3-cycle is a rotation about a line through 4 and of angle $2\pi/3$. But this means that the tetrahedron now will have 3 more symmetries, namely 3 reflections about planes and we get a contradiction.

Comment: You do not need the classification of isometries of $\Bbb{R}^3$ and I did not use it. I used the fact that if there is a cycle $(1,2,3)$;then there is also an involution and so the order of the group of symmetries is even. This is all very elementary.